# Setting up SSL for Google Cloud Storage static website?

Tags: ssl, google-cloud-storage

Is there any way to serve a static website (SPA actually) located on Google Cloud Storage via SSL, for that nice SSL address and icon for users to see?

Amazon allows this via CloudFront SNI.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Yes!

Using GCS directly via CNAME redirects only allows HTTP traffic.

To use HTTPS with your own domain, you'll need to set up Google Cloud Load Balancer, and optionally you'll want to set up Google Cloud CDN as well. While it adds a bit of complexity, Google Cloud Load Balancer allows you to fill a domain with all sorts of content. Some resources could be served by a GCS bucket, but you could also have servers in GCE serving dynamic content for other paths.

There are instructions for setting this up here: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/using-http-lb-with-cloud-storage.

Comment: So the best approach would be to load the SPA from GCE, then serve the assets from GCS (ensuring proper CORS)?

Comment: Via the API I mean (https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/get), getting the browser to load the assets.

Comment: That could certainly work. With proper CORS, Content-Type, etc, you likely wouldn't even need the API. You could just link to the appropriate URL for images, etc: https://storage.googleapis.com/bucket_name/object_name.jpg (unless you need authentication, etc)

Comment: This all seems like a workaround for something which should have been working in first place. Let's report this as a feature request to google. Any idea where could we report it?

Comment: Nope, this is still the case.

Comment: @VladMiller -- Updated with the new answer

Comment: One caveat to this answer is that it looks like a Google Cloud Load Balancer starts at $18/mo ($0.025/hr * 24 * 30) from https://cloud.google.com/compute/pricing#lb.  For a simple static site free SSL via Cloudflare might make more sense.  I'm hoping someone will comment if there's a free tier option I'm missing here.

Comment: @husayt all issues and feature requests can go to https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers, look for the relevant product.

Comment: Theoretically you could do HTTP-only on the GCP side, set up a CNAME from your subdomain to c.storage.googleapis.com, but then add the SSL on cloudflare's side (using the SSL proxy option when configuring the DNS). I say 'theoretically' because to users it looks secure but it masks the possibility of man-in-the-middle between Cloudflare and Google.

Answer (score 21):

As of April 2019:  https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/troubleshooting#https

> HTTPS serving Issue: I want my content served through HTTPS.
>
> Solution: While you can serve your content through HTTPS using direct
>   URIs such as https://storage.googleapis.com/my-bucket/my-object, when
>   hosting a static website using a CNAME redirect, Cloud Storage only
>   supports HTTP. To serve your content through a custom domain over SSL,
>   set up a load balancer, use a third-party Content Delivery Network
>   with Cloud Storage, or serve your static website content from Firebase
>   Hosting instead of Cloud Storage.

Pretty shocking in this day and age that with letsEncrypt everywhere they have not figured out how to do this.

Answer (score 20):

An alternative would be to host your domain DNS server at CloudFlare. They give free HTTPS to HTTP service.

---

*More Info:*

- https://www.cloudflare.com/ssl/
- [Adding HTTPS For Free With CloudFlare](https://pantheon.io/docs/guides/cloudflare-enable-https/)

Comment: For what its worth the free HTTPS is not available on sub-sub domains like hello.world.example.com, however it will work on world.example.com

Comment: Also note that this only encrypts part of the path. The traffic is encrypted from the user to Cloudflare but unencrypted from Cloudflare to GCS.

Answer (score 12):

An alternative would be to host your SPA on Firebase. All apps have SSL included by default even those with custom domains. They also have a CLI that makes it easy to deploy!

Answer (score 5):

If you're not tied to Cloud Storage, another alternative to host your SPA directly on App Engine, using [static files](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/getting-started/serving-static-files).
 Follow [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/getting-started/hosting-a-static-website) for something more compreensive.

If you still want your SPA to be stored in a Cloud Storage bucket, you can use [this](https://github.com/ncruces/appengine-hosting) project to serve it through App Engine. You can host multiple websites with a single app, in fact.

Using App Engine either way, you'll get a free managed certificate, and a free monthly allowance.

Comment: yep, if the allowance fits your needs, for speed and costs cdn is better.

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity use FireBase, the command to update is `ssh firebase deploy` Iv done a few thousand html files in a matter of seconds.

I would also recommend the free service CloudFlare provides as well for an extra level of protection.