# Are static sites hosted on google cloud storage accessable through https?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

According to this post from 2014, https is not available to static sites on google cloud engine: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22767544/46799

Is this still the case? If so, are there any plans add this functionality?

My site is hosted on GCS and I have a cname entry which maps my url to a bucket on GCS. I need to start providing access to the site through https now, am I out of luck?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting up SSL for Google Cloud Storage static website?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22759710/setting-up-ssl-for-google-cloud-storage-static-website)

Answer (score 1):

This is still the case, sorry. You can access GCS via HTTPS, but not via CNAME redirects.