# How to create HTTPS urls on Google Cloud Storage

Tags: https, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, load-balancing

I have [read](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/forwarding-rules) that you need to [configure HTTPS](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/) in order so that your bucket can be used like this:

```
https://my.bucket.com/foo.png
```

However, after looking through those two pages, I still have no idea how to actually configure this in Google Cloud Storage. Wondering if one could quickly show how I go about getting HTTPS working on my Google Cloud Storage bucket `my.bucket.com`. I have the CNAME configured with my DNS system, so `http://my.bucket.com/foo.png` works, but `https://my.bucket.com/foo.png` does not.

I simply have images in my bucket which I want to access via HTTPS. I don't have any compute vms or any of that.

Looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22759710/setting-up-ssl-for-google-cloud-storage-static-website) for inspiration.

Answer (score 1):

Using HTTPS with Google Cloud Storage can be pretty easy, so long as you are not using custom domain names. For example, https://storage.googleapis.com/my.bucket.com/foo.png will work just fine.

If you need to serve those resources from a custom domain name, though, that's a bit trickier.  You have two main options:

1. Use [Firebase Hosting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/custom-domain). Firebase supports custom domain names and serves objects from Google Cloud Storage buckets.
2. [Set up a Google Cloud Load Balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/adding-a-backend-bucket-to-content-based-load-balancing) (GCLB) with a custom domain name and backed by a GCS bucket. The advantage here is that this gives you a lot of additional power and freedom (you can name your bucket whatever you want, you can serve multiple buckets from the same domain name, you can add non-GCS routes, etc). The disadvantage is that load balancers are pretty expensive for smaller use cases and are relatively complicated.

Comment: Mind explaining how to create the load balancer? That's the main part I'm stuck on, I don't follow that article.

Comment: There's a tutorial on setting up a load balancer here: https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/content-based-example#configuring_services_needed_by_the_load_balancing_service. You can ignore the bit about setting up an apache server on GCE and start with the bit about setting up a static IP address.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider creating a [Content-Based Load Balancing](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/content-based-example) and then [Adding a Cloud Storage bucket to content-based load balancing](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/adding-a-backend-bucket-to-content-based-load-balancing)